# Webscraping within Expo

Tags: javascript, express, expo

I'm thinking about writing a phone app to display some data pulled from a website. I want to use Expo since I am already familiar with Javascript, but I have never written or worked on an app before. I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to use something like Express within an app, and display the data pulled from Express on the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to solve problem will be to make [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) Webscraping python API.